# Automatically switch between users in Microsoft Teams

Tags: c#, api, rest, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Due to the current situation, we are organizing exams using Teams (not my choice). So we have to check on every student's webcam from time to time in a meeting. Currently, the (only ?) way to do that is by manually pinning and unpining students in the meeting.

I'm looking for a way to automatically switch between webcams, say every 30 seconds. Looking a the Graph API, I have the impression that it cannot be done simply, since there is no way (?) to control the pinning (say) through a script. It seems, on the other hand, that it would be (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/real-time-media-concepts) possible to get video streams, which would somehow solve my problem.

Is there, somewhere, any documentation that could help me achieve that ? I'm even willing to learn C# if it helps :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide this feedback on Team app. 
Navigate to bottom left corner -> Help -> Suggest Feature

[image]